# jQuery equivalent of $_SERVER[PHP_SELF]

Tags: php, jquery

What is the jQuery equivalent of `$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]`?

I need it so I can insert it into a jQuery function

The jQuery is being called from inside the header

For example I'm trying make a request. This can come from multiple domains hence the need to set it dynamically.

```
$(".class").load( jQuery equivalent $_SERVER[PHP_SELF] "?page=" + pageNumberID + "&ipp=4" etc);
```

Comment: in terms of ajax you can give the path to the page itself (_i think_).

Comment: I think you should calrify your question more.

Comment: You want to have e.g. `foo.html` that contains `foo.html` that contains `foo.html` that...? (And `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` does not contain domain information at all.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the properties of the `window.location` object:

```
$(".class").load(window.location.pathname + "?page=" + pageNumberID + "&ipp=4" etc);
```

Answer (score 3):

You want the name of the JavaScript file you're currently in? It doesn't exist.

Best you can do is `window.location.href` which gives you the (full) URL of the page you're on.

---

What you could consider is a serverside script that wraps all your JavaScript files like:

```
files.add(<?php echo json_encode($filename);?>, function () {
    <?php echo $filecontents;?>
});
```

This allows your to load JavaScript files as modules or 'widgets'.

Comment: `document.location.href` is actually the correct answer. (`PHP_SELF` doesn't give the current file; it gives the current page. for current page in PHP, you'd use `__FILE__`)

Comment: This is PHP not JS/jQuery. And for cross-browser support it's better to use `window.location` instead of `document.location` - http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/#window-location